# Send 1 email notification based on spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some script that I can run to look for empty cells in column "E" and send an email if they are found.  It runs and works.  The problem is, it sends an individual email for every row where column "E" is empty.  I just need one single email sent if empty cells are found in that column.

How can this be accomplished?

```
 function sendSupervisorEmail(e) {
   var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
   {
     if(data[i][4] == "")
     {var msg = "There are time off requests that have an open approval status.  \n Click the following link to approve \n '>>>>URL<<<<'";
     MailApp.sendEmail(">>>>EMAIL<<<<", "Open Approval Status - Time Off Requests", msg, {noReply: true} )}
   }

}
```

Comment: Hint: Should `MailApp.sendEmail` be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send an email if there are ANY blanks in Column E.

- `getLastRow` = number of rows in the sheet
- `sheet.getRange("e1:e").getValues().filter(String).length` = gets the number of records in Column E (ignores blank cells).
- test whether the two values are equal

  - if "no", then send email
  - if "yes", then do nothing

---

```
function sendSupervisorEmail(e) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // get the number of records in Column E
  var eRecords = sheet.getRange("e1:e").getValues().filter(String).length;
  // get the last row in the sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  // send an email if the last row <> number of records
  if (lastRow != eRecords){
    var msg = "There are time off requests that have an open approval status.  \n Click the following link to approve \n '>>>>URL<<<<'";
    MailApp.sendEmail(">>>>EMAIL<<<<", "Open Approval Status - Time Off Requests", msg, {noReply: true} )
  }
}
```